# Turn Time columns into DateTime rows w/ multiple col names unpivotted

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multiple-columns

I need to deal with data in the following format:
[image: Raw Data]

I've found many solutions to sort this type of data but none handling a list of column names to be transposed into the actual columns.

This is what I'm looking to get:

[image: Desired Output]

There are 96 time columns, one for each quarter hour and it ends at 24:00.

Could someone assist me with this?

Comment: Posting pictures of tables isn't really helpful here. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Regarding your problem, you could try with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not providing reproducible code, I realize how much of a nuisance that would be to answer then.

Ended up resolving it with some pandas melt and pivot.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.read_csv(r'dummy_data.csv')

df.drop(columns=['unnecessary_col1', 'unnecessary_col2'], inplace=True)

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['datasource', 'date'], var_name='Time', value_name='value')

df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['Time'], yearfirst=True)

for i in range(len(df)):

    if df.iloc[i,2] == '00:00':
        df.iloc[i,-1] += timedelta(days=1)

df.drop(columns=['date', 'Time'], inplace=True)

df = df.pivot(index='TimeStamp', columns='datasource', values='value').sort_values(by='TimeStamp', ascending=True)
```

Appreciate anyone taking the time.